# Non-real constants

Tags: examples

Constants are usually real numbers e.g. e, pi, gamma etc. Can you give examples of special constants that are not real? e.g. complex or p-adic constants.

A real number in base10 can be viewed as the coefficients of a power series evaluated at x=1/10, so I suppose a constant in another context such as a complete ring could just be some value of a function evaluated at some point. Can you give examples of such a value that could be considered as a special mathematical constant.

More generally a whole object such as a set or group could be thought of as a constant if it appeared in many formulae relating such objects.

Comment: A cute question, the best source for checking is Steven R. Finch's book *Mathematical Constants* (CUP 2003) (unfortunately, I don't have nearby).

Comment: Why stop with complexes and p-adics? What about quaternions or surreal numbers or even stranger number systems?

Comment: I find it rather odd calling a number a "constant". What precisely
makes a number like $\pi$ a "constant"? Surely it's just
an interesting number?

Comment: I think calling numbers constants is due to the influence of physics. 

Comment: Since asking this question I've also come across the term "special values" which is useful because googling "p-adic constants" didn't bring up much but "p-adic" "special values" turns up a lot of things.

Comment: Perhaps the most frequently mentioned object that is not a real number but is a special mathematical constant is $i=\sqrt{-1}. \qquad$

Comment: I like this question! If we generalize and consider “special points in arbitrary Lie groups” then there are some really pretty identities of bill gosper that involve infinite matrix products that converge. These can be viewed as statements involving elements of the underlying Lie group. I need to dig them up.

Answer (score 12):

I have a curious example of $p$-adic constant which can be called
Kurepa--Vladimirov constant, although it's very close to one of Euler's
constants, $-1=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot n!$.

In 1971, D. Kurepa [*Math. Balkanica* **1** (1971) 147--153]
introduced the left factorial $!n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k!$ and investigated its divisibility properties.
One of his conjectures, finally proved by D. Barsky and B. Benzaghou
[*J. Th\'eor. Nombres Bordeaux* **16** (2004) 1--17]
asserts that for any odd prime $p$ the left factorial $!p$ is never
divisible by $p$. This is equivalent to saying that the
corresponding $p$-adic number
$$
\xi=\xi_p=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n!
$$
is a $p$-adic unit, $|\xi|_p=1$ (cf. [V.S. Vladimirov,
*Publ. Inst. Math. (Beograd) (N.S.)* **72(86)** (2002) 11--22]).
On the other hand, a folklore conjecture says that
the number $\xi_p$ is irrational for any prime $p$.
The problem is considered to be hard, since a very similar
number $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\cdot n!$ is $-1$ in any $p$-adic
valuation, the fact already known to L. Euler. Note that $\xi$ is
one of the simplest constants (from the definining series point
of view), for which the expected irrationality was not yet shown.

Answer (score 10):

Well for me the imaginary unit $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is a very natural yet non-real mathematical constant.

Comment: More generally, roots of unity are worth mentioning.

Comment: i is really shorthand for (0,1) so in complexity is on a par with (1,0) so isn't really as interesting as (e,0) or (pi,0).

Answer (score 9):

Alongside the ubiquitous complex period $2\pi i$, there's also the p-adic analogue $t$ which is a uniformiser in Fontaine's period ring $B_{dR}^+$ (see for instance anything written by Colmez e.g. [this](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~colmez/Orsay.pdf)) as well as characteristic $p$ analogues such as the Carlitz period (see e.g. [notes](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/08/08BrownawellPapanikolasNotes.pdf)  of Brownawell and Papanikolas).

Comment: "Carlitz period". I like it.

Answer (score 7):

We often encounter interesting constants as:

1. solutions to interesting equations
2. values of special functions at special inputs
3. integrals of differential forms on geometric objects

The third case is possibly viewable as a special case of the first.  None of these are necessarily constrained to be real.  Here are some examples:

1. Small-order roots of unity (complex or p-adic) have plenty of number-theoretic utility, along with roots of interesting non-cyclotomic polynomials (e.g., $x^p-x-1/p$ in the p-adic world).  We get $2\pi i$ by choosing a generator of the kernel of the exponential map $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, i.e., a special solution to the equation $e^z = 1$.  Integers in imaginary quadratic fields can be viewed as locations of poles of special Weierstrass functions, and the zeroes of the Riemann zeta function are reasonably interesting, although perhaps not as isolated examples.
2. Constants like $e$ and $\gamma$ arise as values of special functions, namely $e^x$ and $-\Gamma'(x)$ at $x=1$.  We can get similar constants in other rings by evaluating special functions in those domains, or taking residues at poles.  For example, certain modular functions evaluated at imaginary quadratic integers yield algebraic integers whose degree depends on class number.
3. We can also think of $2 \pi i$ as the integral of $dz/z$ along a 1-cycle in $\mathbb{C}^\times$.  More complicated constants arise from integrals on cycles in more complicated varieties.  These are known as periods, and they exist in both complex and nonarchimedean worlds.

Answer (score 4):

Initial or terminal objects in categories.

Eg: The integers ${\mathbb{Z}}$ are initial in the category of rings.

Comment: Can you expand the answer?

Comment: Whenever you have any formula relating objects of a category, the initial or terminal object is going to appear. For instance, characteristic involves the initial object, and exact sequences uses zero object.

Comment: I am not sure that these can be counted as constants. But this is subjective.

Comment: Yes it is subjective. But the OP is allows "whole objects... that appear in many formulae that relate such objects."

Answer (score 4):

Since all the known non-trivial zeroes of Riemann Zeta function are on the Re(z)=1/2 line we only give their imaginary parts, but in fact their are complex,

$$1/2+ i*14.1347251417346937904572519835624702707842571156992431756855674601499...$$

being the first above the real line.  If Riemann Hypothesis is true we will never have to mention a different real part.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by a "constant"? The sine function is a very interesting constant in the field of meromorphic functions on the complex plane.

Comment: You can check with Finch's book.

Comment: A field of functions plus a list of some funtions that stand out within that field is a good answer. Why does the sine function stand out amongst meromorphic functions ?

Comment: A variation of the sine function does stand out: $\sin(\pi z)/\pi=z\prod_{n\ne 0}(1-z/n)$ (with the usual interpretation of the product).

Answer (score 3):

Since we do not want to restrict ourselves to values in traditional number systems...

- Each remarquable/exceptional finite algebraic structure, graph, can be described/encoded as a specific value in a numbering system.  For instance as a series of generating matrices, multiplication table, representation tables, etc.
- We can consider each sporadic group as a remarquable constant. To me the Monster Group is a mathematical attraction point that can be compared to $\pi$ or $e$.  And it is well hidden in the armies of soluble groups around it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps $\aleph_0$

Perhaps certain complex roots of L-functions.

Comment: "The only p-adic numbers which aren't real are infinite."  The $p$-adics and the real numbers do not naturally live inside any common field, so I don't know what it means for a $p$-adic number to be real.

Comment: I thought p-adics were Laurent series in p, so that you could evaluate the series as a real number and identify them that way.

Comment: Every element of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has a unique representation as a convergent series $\sum_{n = N_0}^{\infty} a_n p^n$ with `$a_n \in \{0,\ldots,p-1\}$`, yes.  But this series is convergent in the $p$-adic topology.  If $x$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}$, as a real series the terms do not tend to zero, so of course the series diverges.  Maybe this is what you were getting at?  

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I will list some constants groupped mainly into 4 categories: 1) hypercomplex numbers, 2) umbral calculus, 3) formal power series, infinite germs and divergent integrals and series, 4) linear operators (infinite matrices).

1. Hypercomplex numbers

- Split-complex (tessarine) unity $j$. Logarithm: $\ln j=\frac{i \pi }{2}-\frac{i j\pi}{2}$. Has property $i^j=ij$, where $i$ is complex unity.
- Split-complex idempotents and zero divisors $1/2+j/2$ and $1/2-j/2$. Have properies $0^{1/2+j/2}=1/2-j/2$ and $0^{1/2-j/2}=1/2+j/2$
- Dual unity $\varepsilon$ and its roots in higher-dimension algebras (e.g. $\varepsilon_1^2=\varepsilon$), all nilpotents. Has property $f(\varepsilon)=f(0)+\varepsilon f'(0)$
- Grassmann algebra generators $\theta_i$ and their products, also all nilpotents.
- Triplex numbers unities $j_1$ and $j_2$. As well as $c=i^{j_1+j_2}=\frac{1}{3} \left(-\left(\left(\sqrt{3}+1\right) j_1\right)+\left(\sqrt{3}-1\right) j_2-1\right)$ (here $i$ is usual complex unity), satisfying $c^3+c^2+c+1=0$. Logarithm: $\ln j_1=\frac{2 \pi  \left(j_1-j_2\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}$, $\ln c=\frac{1}{3} i \pi  j_1-\frac{\pi  j_1}{2 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{3} i \pi  j_2+\frac{\pi  j_2}{2 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{i \pi }{3}$. $j_1^2=j_2$, $j_2^2=j_1$, $j_1j_2=1$.

2. Umbral calculus

- The most important is Bernoulli's umbra $B^-$ and $B^+=B^-+1$. $\operatorname{eval}(B^-)=-1/2$, $\operatorname{eval}(B^+)=1/2$ (here "eval" is evaluation, akin to taking real part). Logarithm of $B^-$ is undefined, but $\operatorname{eval}(\ln B^+)=-\gamma$. Links logarithms with trigonometric functions: $\operatorname{eval}\frac1{\pi }\ln \left(\frac{B^+-\frac{x}{\pi }}{B^-+\frac{x}{\pi }}\right)=\cot x$.
- $e^{B^-}$ and $e^{B^+}$ respectively have evaluations $\frac 1{e-1}$ and $\frac1{1-1/e}$. $(-1)^{B^-+1/2}$ has evaluation $\frac{\pi}2$.
- Euler's umbra $E$. $\operatorname{eval}E=0;$ $\operatorname{eval}\ln E=-\pi/2$

3. Infinite germs and divergent integrals/series.

- The most simple infinite number $\omega$ is the germ at infinity of the function $f(x)=x$. Denoted in Levi-Civita field as $\varepsilon^{-1}$ (so has inverse $\varepsilon$ in that field, as well as in Hardy field). Can be represented as divergent integrals $\int_0^\infty dx$ and $\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^2}dx$ (via Laplace transform). Half the numerocity of integers, equal to numerocity of even or odd numbers. Divergent sum representation: $1/2+\sum_{k=1}^\infty 1$. Has finite part (regularized value) $0$. Also, the germ of the function $\frac1x$ at zero (from above). If we [modify](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627326/squarable-delta-function) Delta distribution to behave like a function, $\omega=\pi\tilde{\delta}(0)$ (via Fourier transform).
- $\lambda=-\int_0^1 \frac1x dx$. This is negatively infinite constant. Via its definition can be used to extend logarithmic function to zero (thus $\lambda=\ln 0$). Has finite part (regularized value) $-\gamma$. Since Harmonic series is the Riemann sum of this integral, $\lambda$ is the negative of the sum of Harmonic series: $\lambda=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$. From this equality (or via Laplace transform), $\int_1^\infty\frac1xdx=-\lambda-\gamma$. Thus, $\int_0^\infty \frac1x dx=-2\lambda-\gamma$. Other integral representations include: $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}-1}{x}dx,-\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+x}dx$. Can be expressed via $\omega$: $\lambda=-\ln\omega-\gamma$. Some divergent integrals can be expressed in terms of $\lambda$: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln t}{t} \, dt=\gamma\lambda+\gamma^2/2,$ $\int_0^{\infty } | \tan x|  \, dx=-\lambda\omega$. If we generalize the notions of periods and Chow's $EL$-numbers to our extended set, then $\lambda$ would be both, because it can be represented as $\int_0^1 \frac{-1}t dt$ (integral of an algebraic function over algebraic domain) and $\ln 0$ respectively. Logarithms of zero divisors can be expressed via $\lambda$, in split-complex numbers: $\ln \left(\frac{a j}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\right)=\frac{j}{2} (\ln a-\lambda)+\frac{1}{2} (\ln a+\lambda)$, in dual numbers $\ln \varepsilon=\lambda+\varepsilon \omega$, $\varepsilon^\varepsilon=1+\varepsilon(1+\lambda)$.
- $-\lambda-\gamma$. Equal to $\ln \omega$ and germ at infinity of logarithmic function $f(x)=\ln x$. Has finite part $0$. Unlike $\lambda$, is neither generalized period, nor EL-number. Has representations $\int_1^\infty\frac1xdx,$ $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx,$ $\int_0^\infty \frac{x-\log (x)-1}{(x-1)^2}dx$.
- $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^x dx$. Equal to $e^\omega$. Has finite part $0$. Germ of the function $f(x)=e^x$ at infinity.
- $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k=\frac{\omega^2}2-\frac1{12}$ Has finite part $-1/12$.

4. Among infinite matrices one constant is the matrix of derivative operator $D$. Many other operators can be represented via $D$: finite difference $\Delta=e^D-1$, Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}(D^2-x^2+1)}$, scaling $f(x)\to f(ax)=a^{xD}$, etc.

Comment: This seems neat but is mostly all new to me.  Can one somehow bootstrap these "infinite" constants into (divergent) asymptotic expansions?

Comment: @JesseElliott basically if $f(x)$ has germ at infinity (satisfies Hardy fields requirements), then the germ of this function at infinity is $f(\omega)$, in other words (up to infinitesimals), $f(\omega)=f(a)+\int_a^\infty f'(x)dx$

Comment: I'm going to have to give this some further thought.  I'm finishing up writing a book, a chapter of which is on Hardy fields, but I hadn't thought of this particular perspective.  Is it written up anywhere?

Comment: @JesseElliott I think, one can look up formal power series (evaluated at infinity). It is great if you are writing a book on this! I would be glad to contribut and otherwise help!

Comment: I mean, what advantages does one gain by thinking of germs of Hardian functions as "numbers" of a sort?

Comment: I guess there are connections to surreal numbers.

Comment: @JesseElliott well, 1) it allows to represent divergent integrals and series (and not only divergent at infinity but also, via Laplace transform, divergent at a point) as such numbers. 2) Extending reals with logarithm of zero, etc 3) All monotonous sequences have limit in this extended field (a kind of compactification) 4) representing numerocities of sets (counting measures of sets), even of infinite ones.

Comment: @JesseElliott some links: https://mathenchant.wordpress.com/2018/09/16/a-new-game-with-infinity/ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552603/extending-reals-with-logarithm-of-zero-properties-and-reference-request https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4627326/squarable-delta-function

Comment: @JesseElliott well, I think, surreal $\omega$ is the same as $\omega$ in this post except the operations on surreal numbers are defined differently. So, the connection is there but not too much.

Comment: I think I saw somewhere that the connection (which may still be conjectural) is deeper than one might naively think.

Comment: @JesseElliott one more link: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4556566/2513 I also was thinking about uncountable numerocities https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4770070/2513 but this last post I think, has errors in proposed integration rules in the end. Nevertheless, it introduces one more constant, $\alpha$ which cannot be expressed via $\omega$ in closed form.

Comment: Here is a great reference.  The potential connection between Hardy fields and surreal numbers is via transseries.   https://www.texmacs.org/joris/ln/ln.html

Comment: @JesseElliott in surreal numbers, $\ln \omega=\omega^{1/\omega}$. In divergent integrals, $\ln \omega=-\lambda-\gamma$, a different thing. The germ at infinity of the function $x^{1/x}$ is infinitely close to 1.

Comment: @JesseElliott another possible constant, an **uncountable** one (but we can express it as integrals $\alpha=\int_0^1\omega dx=\int_0^\infty\ln \omega dx$, the later equality in itself is fascinating): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787181/introducing-a-new-constant-alpha-this-way-what-will-be-its-properties

Answer (score 0):

Special values of $p$-adic zeta functions, or, more generally, $p$-adic $L$-functions.  Start with the most basic fact that $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty p^n = 1/(1-p)$ in the ring of $p$-adic integers.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_L-function