# Construction, similar to Chow's EL-numbers? Is it valid? What are the properties?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, fields, euler-mascheroni-constant

The idea of [EL-numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388591/is-the-euler-mascheroni-constant-an-el-number), proposed by Chow, impressed me very much, so I decided to build something similar and look what this will turn out.

Instead of $\exp(x)$ and $\ln(x)$ functions as the building blocks, let us take the following ones:

$l(x)=\ln \Gamma(x)$
and its derivative, digamma function:

$\psi(x)=l'(x)$

We apply these functions, as well as field operations, starting with number $1$.

So, what do we get?
$$\pi=\psi(3/4)-\psi(1/4)$$
$$\gamma=-\psi(1)$$
$$i=\frac{l(2)-l(3)+l\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)-l\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\psi\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}$$
$$e=\frac{i \pi +\left(\psi \left(\frac{i}{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i }{2 \pi }\right)\right)}{i \pi -\left(\psi \left(\frac{i }{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i }{2 \pi }\right)\right)}$$

Moreover, we can express $e^x$ and $\ln x$ via these two functions:

$$e^x=\frac{i \pi +\left(\psi \left(\frac{i x}{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i x}{2 \pi }\right)\right)}{i \pi -\left(\psi \left(\frac{i x}{2 \pi }+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i x}{2 \pi }\right)\right)}$$

$$\ln x=l(x+1)-l(x)$$

As such, it turns out that the EL-numbers are a subset of this system.

That said, I wonder whether one of the functions I took as the elements is excessive? Can we keep the same system, using only one of them? Or, maybe, $\psi^{(1/2)}(x)$? What would be the qualities of the respective systems if we included only one?

What if, instead, we include all integer derivatives of digamma $\psi^{(n)}(x)$? It seems, in the later case, Catalan constant also can be expressed (as $\frac1{16}(\psi'(3/4)-\psi'(1/4))$).

P.S. It seems, if we take $i$ as the basic number, we can express $\pi, \gamma, e$ using only digamma function, without need for the first function.

Comment: This question has been posted on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4119465/) as well. -- When cross-posting, please give links between both instances of your question.